# running C++ program on xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

when I run a simple C++ program on Xcode, the compiler says it's built successfully, but there is no output. how can I make the result show up? thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about text output (like in a terminal window), or binary output (like a library or executable)?

Comment: i'm talking about text output

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> is the default "build and run" keyboard hotkey.  Once you've pressed that, use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> to open the console and see your program's output.

Answer (score 1):

in the tab Groups and file, under the xcode icon of your project there are 3 folders, Source, Documentation, Products, under Products there is your executable.
hth